# Kotlin coroutine not stopping when Android app terminates

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

It seems I don't understand Kotlin coroutine scope like I thought I did.  I was under the impression that a coroutine was automatically canceled when the scope ended.  I start an infinitely looped coroutine conditioned with 'isActive.':

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            while (isActive)
            {
                log(this, object {}, "Hello GlobalScope", false)
                delay(500)
            }
        }
        ...
```

Since it uses the global scope I expected it to stop when the app is terminated but instead it keeps running after the app is terminated:

```
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
I/BluetoothLeash: StandaloneCoroutine.invokeSuspend(): Hello GlobalScope
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: try to use lifecycleScope.launch { } The documentation said:  * This scope will be cancelled when the [Lifecycle] is destroyed.

Comment: GlobalScope is tied to your application lifecycle which is not destroyed
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/

Comment: @IvanWooll but the documentation you mention states that: A global CoroutineScope not bound to any job. Global scope is used to launch top-level coroutines which are operating on the whole application lifetime and are not cancelled prematurely.  Which suggest it will get canceled when the app terminates...

Comment: Yeah my wording could be better there. Maybe a better way would be to say that it lives in the same process as your app.I suppose it depends on what you mean when you say that the app is terminated. If you don't explicitly kill the app process then it can live on for some time after the app closes

Comment: @ManuelMato Thanks, that works!  Please write your solution as an 'answer' so that I can accept it and others can quickly see the answer.  I am however still curious why it doesn't terminate with global scope...

Comment: @IvanWooll so I open the recently opened apps tab on my Android phone and close all.

Comment: Simply put, `GlobalScope` never terminates. It is theoretically impossible for it to terminate because its associated `coroutineContext` is completely empty. It has no state at all, and that includes not having an `isActive` flag. Also remember that, when you launch a coroutine in a scope, that coroutine gets its own coroutine context, which always has a job. The job is a child of the scope's job, if there is one.

Comment: If you kill your app, co-routine launched on GlobalScope should be terminated as well, as the process also gets killed when app is killed. Unless you have not swiped away and app is just minised.

Comment: @Ritesh No, the app was terminated ('closed all' on recent page).  After which there were no apps on recent page.  Apparently static objects are independent of the app and are NOT stopped when the app stops.  GlobalScope is a static object and so remains active when the app is closed.  Look at the excepted answer as well as my clarification in the last comment...

Comment: @David this is strange, i have added my query as a comment in the accepted answer.

Comment: @David Any possibility  - your app process is alive after you swiped it away.
After swiping the app away, can you go to the apps setting and check if it's stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the definition of GlobalScope you will find that it is declared as an object:

```
object GlobalScope : CoroutineScope { ... }
```

And an object represents a static instance. So it will consume some memory while your app is running. And even if your app is terminated but the process is not destroyed, a launched coroutine in GlobalScope may still be running.

> GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO): Launches a top-level coroutine on
> Dispatchers.Default. This coroutine is unbound and keeps running until
> the task is finished or cancelled

Use GlobalScope may be a bad idea because it is not bound to any job.

> Global scope is used to launch top-level coroutines which are
> operating on the whole application lifetime and are not cancelled
> prematurely.

Comment: but wouldn't a static instance be destroyed and hence the coroutines canceled when the app is closed?

Comment: does anyone know why the static instance would not be destroyed when the app is closed and thereby canceling the coroutine?

Comment: So the thing I misunderstood, I now see, is that a static object is separate from the app and is NOT terminated when the app terminates as Pranav Choudhary stated.  The only way to eliminate the object is to reset the phone or reinstall the app.  My app is reinstalled every time I debug it and hence this bug never showed up in debug mode

Comment: I am finding hard to understand, how avoiding GlobalScope (i agree that using GlobalScope is not correct), solves this problem, when app is swiped away, which results in it's process being killed as well, unless you have a foreground service or something which is keeping the process alive and in that case static object will be in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use lifecycleScope.launch { } The documentation said:

- This scope will be cancelled when the [Lifecycle] is destroyed.

Comment: I appreciate your answer as it was a solution to the problem but I switched the accepted answer to @PranavChoudhary because his answer answered the question, "what am I missing" as in WHY doesn't this work.  His answer not only provided an implicit solution but gave me more general knowledge going forward.  Thanks again